# read input variable in makefile and set variable upon it`s name

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile where I want to read module name from input and then make directory based on it`s name. here is my code:

```
build:  
    @read -p "Enter Module Name:" module;  
    module_dir=./modules/$$module  
    mkdir -p $$module_dir/build;
```

But after setting **module_dir**, it contains only **./modules/** (with no module name concatenated).
What is wrong in my code?

thanks for your answers

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Each command runs in its own subshell, so variables can't survive from one command to the next. Put them on the same line and they'll work:

```
build:  
    @read -p "Enter Module Name:" module; \  
    module_dir=./modules/$$module; \
    mkdir -p $$module_dir/build
```

Comment: You can also use [`.ONESHELL`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/One-Shell.html) to effectively put all the commands on the same line.